# How to change selected tab title color

Tags: android, tabs, android-actionbar, styles

I need to change **selected tab color** in my tab activity.

For example, selected item text color must be `#cea939`, and unselected items colors have to be `#d7ba60`. What should I do to change that? Actually, I tried to add textColor value to `apptheme_tab_indicator.xml` - but no result. By the way, I use `AppCompat`. And if there is a solution, how does it vary for `styles` and `styles-v21`?

Comment: Check my answer for the post [How to change Viewpager tab colour dynamically?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28881599/how-to-change-viewpager-tab-colour-dynamically/28883927#28883927)

Comment: @Xcihnegn but i need to change text color, not background

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check my answer for the post [How to change Viewpager tab colour dynamically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28881599/how-to-change-viewpager-tab-colour-dynamically/28883927#28883927), use custom view for tabs, and chage the codes of background color setting to text color setting:

```
Tab selectedTab = yourActionBar.getSelectedTab();
View tabView = selectedTab.getCustomView();
TextView text = (TextView)tabView.findViewById(R.id.your_text_id);  
text.setColor(your_text_color);
```

Hope this help!

Comment: That doesn't work for me. I don't use TabActivity, so can't get TabHost. I use ActionBarActivity and implement TabListener. This is how i add tabs: for (int i = 0; i < mSectionsPagerAdapter.getCount(); i++) {
                    actionBar.addTab(
                            actionBar.newTab()
                                    .setText(mSectionsPagerAdapter.getPageTitle(i))
                                    .setTabListener(mActivity));
                } And actually i don't know how to change selected tab title color here. I could change color in onTabSelected, but how?

Comment: My answer is exact for your issue, which is using `ActionBar`, nothing to do with `TabActivity`